# Cause of comparing long slower than comparing double

Tags: java, optimization, runtime, double, long-integer

I wrote a little program to calculate the first 18 triples `(x,y,z)` with `x<y<z`, which satisfy `x^3+y^3=z^3+1`.

While playing around to optimise the total runtime, I discovered, that using `double` for the cubic values and the two sides of the equation is faster than using `long`. On my machine the difference is about 3 seconds.

Now I wonder why exactly this is the case. I guess it is somewhere in the internal handling of `long` while the comparison of two `long`-Variables, as this is the only thing, which changes within the calculation loops.

Here is my code:

```
class Threes {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Threes --- Java");
    int Z_MAX = 60000, Y_MAX = Z_MAX-1, X_MAX = Y_MAX-1;
    double[] powers = new double[Z_MAX+1];
    for (int i = 0; i <= Z_MAX; i++) {
      powers[i] = Math.pow(i, 3);
    }
    System.out.println("Powers calculated");
    int x, y, z;
    double right, left;
    int[][] sets = new int[18][3];
    int foundCount = 0;
    long loopCount = 0;
    long start, end;
    start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    for (x = 1 ; x < X_MAX; x++) {
      for (y = x + 1; y < Y_MAX; y++) {
        right = powers[x] + powers[y];
        for (z = y + 1; z < Z_MAX; z++) {
          left = powers[z] + 1;
          if (right < left) {
            z = Z_MAX;
          } else if (right == left) {
            sets[foundCount][0] = x;
            sets[foundCount][1] = y;
            sets[foundCount][2] = z;
            foundCount++;
            end = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("found " + foundCount + ". set:\t" + x + "\t" + y + "\t" + z + "\t" + ((end - start) / 1000.0));
            if (foundCount == 18) {
              x = X_MAX;
              y = Y_MAX;
              z = Z_MAX;
            }
          }
          loopCount++;
        }
      }
    }
    System.out.println("finished: " + loopCount);
  }
}
```

The lines I changed are:

```
double[] powers = new double[Z_MAX+1];
```

becomes

```
long[] powers = new long[Z_MAX+1];
```

and

```
powers[i] = Math.pow(i, 3);
```

becomes

```
powers[i] = (long)Math.pow(i, 3);
```

and

```
double right, left;
```

becomes

```
long right, left;
```

---

*"Bonus Question"*: What other possibilities of optimizing the whole code in terms of total runtime do I have? I know, that leaving out the `loopCount` gives me some milliseconds. I'm sure, that I have to reduce the number of loop iterations significantly. But how?

Comment: Maybe also try `i*i*i` instead of `Math.pow(i, 3)`? - This will not effect on your measured run time, since it is outside of the measuring block, though.

Comment: Just to make sure: do you get the same results with long and double?

Comment: @Ebermann: Yes, the results are the same.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are using 32-bit operating system the performance for long-variable could be worse because long is 64-bit type. For example, with 64-bit OS Java could do the comparison with just one machine instruction, but in 32-bit environment it has to use multiple machine instructions, since it can only handle 32-bit at the time.

But for double, this is not neccessary the case, since 32-bit systems have machine instructions for 64-bit floating point numbers, even when thet don't have them for 64-bit integers.

Also, with code:

```
powers[i] = (long)Math.pow(i, 3);
```

there is two unneccesary conversions, first i (integer) is converted to double (that's what Math.pow takes) and then the return value is converted back to 64-bit integer (long).

Comment: First explanation sounds reasonable. But the cast is not executed during the benchmark, the stop watch starts after that line.

Comment: I think the question is more about the CPU than the OS, here. But in general, it is right.

Comment: +1: I suspect the unnecessary conversions are a big part of it.

Comment: @Don: The conversions are happening outside of the timed section.

Comment: First: I timed everything on a 32bit machine. I timed that generation of the powers several times with `long` and `double` and there is basically no real difference (~0.15 secs in both cases). Thank's for your explanation of 32bit-systems handling `long`. This seems to be the reason.

Comment: I rerun the program on a 64bit machine with the suggested optimisation of Oli Charlesworth and gained a speed-up of about 5 seconds with `long` over `double`. No it takes approximately 38 seconds.

Comment: @Oli: Ok, I see that now.  Glad I made that just a wrong comment instead of a wrong answer!

Answer (score 3):

It's probably fair to say that your code spends most of its time in this section:

```
for (z = y + 1; z < Z_MAX; z++) {
    left = powers[z] + 1;
     if (right < left) {
        z = Z_MAX;
     }
```

And most of the time, it will always be taking the same branch out of the conditional.  So once your code has reached the steady-state (i.e. once the CPU's branch predictor is set up), the run-time will be dominated by the computation itself: dependencies are minimised, so the latency of the instruction pipeline doesn't matter.

On a 32-bit machine, doing addition and comparison on 64-bit integer types takes more instructions than doing the equivalent on `double`s.  A `double` calculation will take more cycles to complete, but that doesn't matter.  We're dominated by instruction throughput, not latency.  So the overall run-time will be longer.

In terms of further optimization, you could move the +1 outside the inner loop, by calculating `right = powers[x] + powers[y] - 1`.  But it's possible the optimizer has already spotted that.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I agree, that most of the time is spent in this `for`-`if`-construct. However, moving the -1 outside of the `z`-loop does not make a noticeable difference.

Answer (score 1):

Your biggest "bonus" optimization will be to replace the `z` loop with a calculation like:

```
z = Math.round(Math.pow(left - 1, 1./3));
```

and check if `z > y && left == powers[(int)z] + 1`.

Other improvements if you wanted to find all triples within your limits:

- start `x` at 2 instead of 1
- replace `z = Z_MAX;` with `break;` to exit the loop early
- compute `X_MAX` as `Math.pow((powers[Z_MAX] + 1)/2, 1./3)` ~= `Z_MAX * Math.pow(0.5, 1./3)` since if `x` is bigger than that, `z` will exceed `Z_MAX`
- recompute `Y_MAX` for each `x` as `Math.pow(powers[Z_MAX] - powers[x] + 1, 1./3)/2`

BTW, a more common way to order the triples would be using z as the primary sort key, which may result in a different first 18 than you get ordering by x first. To change that, you'd make your outer loop iterate over z, which would be simpler anyway:

```
for (z = 1; z < Z_MAX; z++) {
    for (y = 1; y < z - 1; y++) {
       zy = powers[z] - 1 - powers[y];
       x = Math.round(Math.pow(zy, 1./3));
       if (x < y && zy == powers[(int)x])
           ...report triple found;
    }
}
```